# Getting position/width/height of MainWindow

Tags: wpf

I'm wondering about the best way to get information about the current position and width/height of the MainWindow. I want to keep a child window inside the main window so I want to check the coordinates of the MainWindows borders during the move function of the child window.
I could only find the Window.LocationChanged event but it doesn't solve my problem in a satisfying way. Are there better options?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can access the position of the main window all over your code via `Application.Current.MainWindow.Left` and `Application.Current.MainWindow.Top`, respectively. Hope this will help.

Comment: this only works if you only have one window or it is the main window of the application. I found a better solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8056464/937093)

Answer (score 4):

But, you should check "WindowState". In "Maximized" state properties "Left" and "Top" keep the values of the window in it's normal state.
Window position in "Maximized" state discribes here: [How can I find the position of a maximized window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806088/how-can-i-find-the-position-of-a-maximized-window)